# Label's frame size does not change in tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I am working in storyboard. I have View Controller inherited from tableViewVC. In that vc I have cells with one or 2 lines of text. If I have one line, I just assign text to a custom textLabel in custom Cell. If I have 2 lines, I resize the labels frame. But it does not work when the table is loaded. I can see my resized labels in cell only after I scroll tableView up/down. How can I fix it?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
OptionItem *item = _currentOptionsList[indexPath.row];

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"OptionSimpleCellIdentifier";
OptionSimpleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.titleLabel.text = item.title;
cell.haveDetail = item.haveDetailItems;
cell.selectedSimpleOption = item.simpleSelected;
if (item.haveSelectedDetailItem)
{
    cell.detailLabel.text = [item.detailItems[item.indexOfSelecteDetaildItem] title];

} else {
    cell.detailLabel.text = nil;
    cell.detailImageView.image = nil;
}


CGFloat textHeight = [Calculatons getLabelHeightForText:item.title andWidth:225 withFont:kFontListCell withMaxHeight:0];//19 - 39
CGRect rect = cell.titleLabel.frame;

NSLog(@"textHeight = %f cell.height = %f titleLabel.height %f \n",textHeight, cell.frame.size.height, cell.titleLabel.frame.size.height);

if (textHeight > 21)
{
    rect.size.height = 41;
    cell.titleLabel.frame = rect;
}


  //nothing of this not works
  [cell.titleLabel layoutIfNeeded];
    [cell.titleLabel setNeedsLayout];
[cell.titleLabel setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
  [cell.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:0];

return cell;
}
```

http://s23.postimg.org/8tszefzbf/Screen_Shot_2014_08_27_at_10_01_10_PM.png

After the first screen, i push the VS. second screen is what is shown after i scroll the table up and down.

I need second screen as a result after i push VC.

Answer (score 1):

try  using this earlier in the code, right after the cell is initialised instead of after the value is set to the label.

```
CGFloat textHeight = [Calculatons getLabelHeightForText:item.title andWidth:225 withFont:kFontListCell withMaxHeight:0];//19 - 39
CGRect rect = cell.titleLabel.frame;

NSLog(@"textHeight = %f cell.height = %f titleLabel.height %f \n",textHeight, cell.frame.size.height, cell.titleLabel.frame.size.height);

if (textHeight > 21)
{
    rect.size.height = 41;
    cell.titleLabel.frame = rect;
}
```